# details of (Inkscape) SVG to PDF/X conversion through Scribus

Tags: inkscape, svg, pdf, cmyk, scribus

I am trying to gain  understanding of some of the nuances of the workflow described in [Inkscape SVG → print-ready EPS/PDF workflow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60200).

The general approach is to ensure that an SVG document generated by Inkscape represents colors using a printer-ready color model, then to generate a PDF/X document using the export feature of Scribus. Generating the PDF/X file in Scribus is a process with two major steps, to complete after opening the file in the application. The first is activating    color management for the document, and the second is exporting to a PDF document.

A few questions emerge:

1. In *Color Management* under *Document Setup* an option appears labeled "Convert all colors to printer space". While it may be unwise to accept an automatic conversion  from an RGB representation of black, in many cases automatic conversation may be agreeable. Does use of this option have the same effect as the use of the CMS tab in Inkscape to give a color representation according to the target profile, if the default CMYK values for conversion by Inkscape would have been used? That is, would this option allow me to bypass using the CMS tab for certain colors, without harmful effects, by allowing Scribus to convert the colors from an RGB representation given by Inkscape?
2. A color profile called *ISO Coated v2 300%* appears abundantly in the default values for options in *Color Management*  as well as in the default value for *Output Intent* in the *Prepress* section of the PDF export settings. Is this choice appropriate for use with documents  originating in Inkscape with the  the color profile *eciCMYK* (which was recommended to me for use with Inkscape documents targeting a CMYK printer target)? Should I instead  select  *eciCMYK*   for any of these options in Scribus, to match the original Inkscape document?
3. Related to the above, the default value for options related to the RGB color model is *sRGB display profile*. Is this value normally preferred over the alternative, also available, labelled simply *sRGB*?

*As may be apparent, these topics are new to me, part of a recreational project rather than a career. Hopefully answers would avoid  a large amount of unnecessary detail, and explain, or provide references to explanations for, any topics mentioned that   may be unfamiliar.*

Comment: You need to talk to your printer. When you do a CMYK conversion then your designing for a specific printer in mind.

Comment: Yes, information from the printer may be needed to resolve which options I would choose, but the principle object of the question is to clarify how to apply such information with respect to use of the software. if the printer is familiar with processing PDF documents, but ignorant of generating them through this workflow, then  communication with the printer is unlikely to resolve fully for me how to proceed.

Comment: (For reference, the information directly and currently made available from the printer is  the following: "All spot, RGB, and PMS colors must be converted to CMYK. Remove all ICC profiles before creating your PDF.")

Comment: For clarification, a simplified version of this question might be, respecting the preferred values of the various options, what information must I ask from the printer, and how should I use the answer to select the values.

Comment: @epl welcome here, please edit this extra information from your own comments into your question; it will help members to provide a better answer

Comment: Recreational might indicate that your budget is limited (or totally unlimited, depending). If you found a good print shop, and you are starting a new relationship, they might be willing to look at a PDF "sample upload" and then give you feedback. For example our own preferred print shop does something similar for the reasonable fee of 16 Euros. So you could just use all the defaults and make a record and have the export evaluated before commiting money for actual printing. Sorry, you wanted a more general answer but finally you want good prints, so consider a pragmatic approach.

Comment: @Martin: I can try to tweak the presentation slightly, but I'm not sure quite how to make it any more plain. The intention is to build a general understanding of the processes in Scribus. While specific suggestions for action are welcome, I would at least like to understand, and to create a space so that others might also learn, what the meaning is of the various fields in Scribus, and the general ways that they may be used (or disregarded) by printers who receive the documents.

Comment: @epl Thank you for clarifying what you want. This place can also help with fundamental issues but works better for specific problems, normally finding workable solutions, often on deadlines. I like your intention, but you might be better placed in the Scribus community (very helpful and active mail list) and contributing there to the Scribus wiki. I still hope you find out more details, because we are more and more producing through digital print shops - and have had some surprises with colour managment. I will bookmark your question. Sorry I cannot provide the details you want to find.

Comment: @Martin: Curious that the policy you describe is almost exactly opposite that of other SE communities, based on my understanding.

Comment: @epl What policy am I describing? I am just another user here, not an admin or anything. If I shared something above, it would not automatically be a policy, just personal advice. Sorry if I created a missunderstanding.